# Basic Python Programming - writing data in a file

Tags: python

I am just a beginner to programming and below is the code that I have written in python to save and edit a file but every time I run the programme it erases the previous save data, so I am confused why it's happening?

```
filename = raw_input("Please enter the file name to open it:\n")
doc = open (filename,'w')
print doc.read
text_input = raw_input("Please enter the data you want to enter in file:\n")
if text_input == "":
    print "no input closing the programme."
else :
    doc.write(text_input)
    doc.close()
print "Printing the file:\n"
print doc.read
cl_file = raw_input("do you want to truncate file(y/n): ")
if cl_file == "y":
    doc.truncate()
else :
    print "Wrong input closing notepad"
    exit()
```

Comment: When you are opening the file use `w+` file open mode.

Comment: @bhansa according to python's documentation, `w+` will truncate the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are opening the file in write mode, which truncates the file before writing to it. Instead of using `open(filename, 'w')` use `open(filename, 'a')`. The 'a' value tells the open function to use append mode so that writes to the file are added to the end of any existing content.

Comment: Thank a lot Jones & Bhansa for answering my queries :)